# Regex pattern matching issue

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

Below is the text I am trying to match

```
3 INFO  ~ [com.Engine:164] italics
```

with

```
(?<=~\s\[)([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)(?=:)(?<=:)(.*)(?=\])
```

I need to fetch 2 expressions out of it -

1. `com.Engine`
2. `164`

and I do not need any more matches, not even the `:`.

```
(?<=~\s\[)([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)(?=:)
```

is returning me `com.Engine` however the total regex doesn't give me any result.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
(?<=~\s\[)([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+):[^]]+
```

Example : http://regex101.com/r/kT6vO6/1

- `:[^]]+` matches anything other than `]` presceded by a `:`

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\[)[^:]+|(?<=:)[^\]]+
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/38

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the rules for the individual parts, but how about:

```
.*\[(.*):(\d*)\].*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I='3 INFO  ~ [com.Engine:164] italics';
J=I.replace(/^.*?\[(.*?)\].*$/,'$1').split(':');
alert(J[0]+'\n'+J[1]);
```